# Load and upload data to table according to selected option value. Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have `select` dropdown:

```
<select class="chooseWatchlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedWatchlist">
 <option *ngFor="let item of items" value="">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

It looks like:
[image]

`items` is just a json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "xid": "WL_621542",
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "pierwsza",
    "pointList": [],
    "watchListUsers": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "xid": "WL_616873",
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "druga",
    "pointList": [],
    "watchListUsers": []
  }
]
```

I just want the data to change when u click on different options in select.

The data table:

```
 <table>
    <tr [selectedWatchlist]>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.xid }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.userId }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: If you already have selectWatchList then you should be able to access it in your table.... try the code below.
`<table>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ selectedWatchList.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ selectedWatchList.xid }}</td>
      <td>{{ selectedWatchList.userId }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `ngModel`?

Try 
`<select class="chooseWatchlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedWatchlist">`

And then
`<table> <tr> <td>{{ selectedWatchList.name }}</td> <td>{{ selectedWatchList.xid }}</td> <td>{{ selectedWatchList.userId }}</td> </tr> </table>`

Comment: What is new in your answer?